# fabric 2 traffic generation with non-blocking commands

Tags: python, virtualenv, fabric

I need to run some tests with a traffic generator that has different client and server commands.  I would like to roll this into a [fabric2](https://github.com/fabric/fabric) script which executes the traffic generation commands while cd'd into `/root`.

I have public-key authentication on the iperf machines. How can I run this traffic generation test under fabric2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a little interesting to get running because the fabric2 docs don't include much information about `run()` arguments... you need to look at the [invoke `Runner.run()`](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/blob/master/invoke/runners.py) documentation to see all fabric `run()` keywords.

The key to making `iperf` work in this case was setting `pty=True` and `asynchronous=True` when I run the iperf server commands.  If I did not run the iperf server as asynchronous, it would block execution of the iperf client command.

```py
# Save this script as run_iperf.py and run with "python run_iperf.py"
from getpass import getuser
import os

#from fabric import Config, SerialGroup, ThreadingGroup, exceptions, runners
#from fabric.exceptions import GroupException
from fabric import Connection

server_vm = "10.1.0.1"
client_vm = "10.2.0.1"

# This matters because my user .ssh/id_rsa.pub is authorized on the remote sytems
assert getuser()=="mpenning"

hosts = list()
conn1 = Connection(host=client_vm, user="root",
    connect_kwargs={"key_filename": os.path.expanduser("~/.ssh/id_rsa")})
conn2 = Connection(host=server_vm, user="root",
    connect_kwargs={"key_filename": os.path.expanduser("~/.ssh/id_rsa")})
hosts.append(conn1)
hosts.append(conn2)

iperf_udp_client_cmd = "nice -19 iperf3 --plus-more-client-commands"
iperf_udp_server_cmd = "nice -19 iperf3 --plus-more-server-commands"

# ThreadingGroup is optional for this use case, but the iperf commands
#     definitely require pty and asynchronous (server-side)...
#     ThreadingGroup() is required for concurrent fabric commands.
#
# Uncomment below to use ThreadingGroup()...
# t_hosts = ThreadingGroup.from_connections(hosts)
#
# also ref invoke Runner.run() for more run() args:
#     -> https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/blob/master/invoke/runners.py
with conn2.cd("/root"):
    conn2.run(iperf_udp_server_cmd, pty=True, asynchronous=True, disown=False, echo=True)
    
with conn1.cd("/root"):
    conn1.run("sleep 1;%s" % iperf_udp_client_cmd, pty=True, asynchronous=False, echo=True)
```

This script was loosely based-on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53763786/667301